# method get of class GregorianCalendar?

Tags: java, get, calendar

I have problems using the class `GregorianCalendar` in Java.
Why does the method `get` change my variable of type `GregorianCalendar`?

I do this work:

```
System.out.println(timestart);
second = timestart.get(GregorianCalendar.SECOND);
System.out.println(timestart);
```

The output is:

```
,HOUR_OF_DAY=15,MINUTE=37,SECOND=16,MILLISECOND=794140,ZONE_OFFSET=?,DST_OFFSET=?]
,HOUR=3,HOUR_OF_DAY=15,MINUTE=50,SECOND=30,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=3600000,DST_OFFSET=3600000]
```

For simplicity, I have shown the interesting part of the output.
I expect that the two prints give the same result, but isn't it.

Comment: show us the instantiation of timestart

Comment: Running this code (with `timestart` initialized with `new GregorianCalendar()`) I see two identical Strings produced. Are any other threads operating on the object referenced by the `timestart` variable? (Are you sharing the object with other threads?)

Comment: Is timestart `GregorianCalendar` for sure ?? :> :)

Comment: I solved the problem. 
Simply gave problems with the milliseconds saved with 6 digits instead of 3. 

Thank you for availability

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source code of [GregorianCalendar](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/GregorianCalendar.java) and [Calendar](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Calendar.java), you can see that [`get`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Calendar.java#Calendar.get%28int%29) first calls a method named `complete` which either calls `updateTime` or `computeFields` - a method that calculates fields like minutes, seconds, etc. based on the calendar's timestamp.

Whenever a value is changed, all fields will be invalidated. Fields seem to be only recalculated on access, presumably to avoid unnecessary calculations if you never don't use them. So basically it is lazy loading those fields.

The `toString` method on the other hand simply prints all values, without recalculating anything. So in your code the first output probably shows old values that are not valid anymore. If this is the case, then you should see something like `areFieldsSet=false` in the omitted part of the first output.